# How to assign function to keyboard function key in Visual Basic

Tags: hotkeys, basic

I'm trying to create a program in Visual Basic to assign a function key to print a screenshot of the current screen and another one to print a list of the files in the currently selected folder in File Explorer.

The key assignments need to remain active even after the program that assigns the keys has been closed.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Yes someone does.  But what have you tried?  Users on SO will help you after **you help yourself**.  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Nic3500, yes, I did read those, but as I don't have any code examples, because I haven't been able figure out where to start, I can't apply them, so all I could do was ask the question. Any actual help to be able to achieve this task would be very welcome.

Comment: Then Stack Overflow is not the site for you. Stack Overflow is a Q&A (Question and Answer) site for **specific** programming related issues and questions. It is not a code-writing service, nor a site where we'll "point you in the right direction". It is up to you to do the research and try something on your own, then you can come here when you bump into an actual problem. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more information on how this site works.